# Уточнить названия режимов просмотра в истории редактирования ответов

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, локализация

Кнопки для переключения между режимами показа diff'а:

[image: русский перевод]

Сравните с оригиналом:

[image: оригинал]

Answer (score 3):

Объединение вариантов нескольких авторов.

- inline - внутристрочный.
- side-by-side - в две колонки.
- side-by-side markdown – разметка в две колонки.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю следующее:

- "в ряд" → "рядом" или даже "в две колонки"
- "встраиваемый" → "встроенный"

Comment: ...и второй вариант стоит отделить в отдельный ответ, дабы голосование шло за комбинации.

Answer (score 1):

Прямой перевод *inline* не очень отражает суть, альтернативный вариант:

- inline — вложенный

  - "изменённые части *вложены* прямо в документ"
- side-by-side — бок-о-бок

Answer (score 0):

Более прямые переводы оригинала:

- inline — внутристрочный
- side-by-side — бок-о-бок

Answer (score 0):

- inline - по тексту
- side-by-side - сравнение
- side-by-side markdown - сравнение разметки